# Closing Active Element in React Accordion Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm building out a simple accordion component for a product page in my Next.js/react app. I've got it mostly working, however when a user clicks open a new accordion item I need to close the active one. Here's what my component looks like:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

import css from 'classnames';

import s from './ProductAccordion.module.scss';

interface FeatureProps {
  title: string;
  copy: string;
}

export const ProductAccordion = ({ content }: any) => {
  return (
    <div className={s.productAccordion}>
      {content.features.map((feature: FeatureProps) => {
        const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
        const activeClass = active ? 'active' : '';

        const toggleAccordion = () => {
          setActive(!active);
        };

        return (
          <div
            className={css(s.productAccordion__section, s[activeClass])}
            key={feature.title}
          >
            <button className={s.sectionTitle} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
              <p className={s.sectionTitle__title}>{feature.title}</p>
              <span className={s.button} />
            </button>

            <div className={css(s.sectionContent, s[activeClass])}>
              <div className={s.sectionContent__copy}>{feature.copy}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I get my active accordion item to close when a new one is clicked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

- moving your `useState` hook a level higher
- instead of "active" being a boolean, make it a string that you can use to identify which item should be active
- hopefully a `feature` has a unique identifier like an id or something that you can use to identify

You could do something like:

```js
export const ProductAccordion = ({ content }: any) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(''); // set up your useState here, so its value is available to all children elements

  return (
    <div className={s.productAccordion}>
      {content.features.map((feature: FeatureProps) => {

        const isActive = active === feature.id // feature.id here is just a stand in for some unique identifier that each feature has
     
        const activeClass = isActive ? 'active' : '';

        const toggleAccordion = () => {
          if (isActive) {
           setActive(''); // if the current item is active, and you toggle it, close the accordian
          } else {
           setActive(feature.id) // if the current item is not active, and you toggle it, open this section
          }
        };

        return (
          <div>
           {/* your code here */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Of course, there are many approaches you could take, and I'm sure a more elegant one than this exists. But this should hopefully get you in the right direction!